# Start a PowerShell Admin SubShell attached to Same Console that started it

Tags: powershell, admin

Is there a way to start a PowerShell Admin SubShell that is attached to the same console as the non-admin powershell Console?  And then when finished type "exit" and return back to the "non-admin" PowerShell. I need something that works simular to "su" linux command.

Presently the way I'm doing it pops up a new window and that gets annoy after awhile, example:

```
PS> start-process -Verb RunAs Powershell
```

Update:

I can almost get it working as follows:

```
PS> start-process -nnw -wait powershell
```

This works to open a subshell in the same console.  Except when I add the "-Verb RunAs" to convert it to an Admin shell. it fails.

```
PS C:\Users\john> start-process -nnw -wait -Verb RunAs powershell
Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-process -nnw -wait -Verb RunAs powershell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Update2:

I found out from microsoft webpage that "-Verb RunAs" isn't possible to use with -nnw..  My feeling is that its possible to get around this using -Credential  flag to specify an Admin Account. However, Since i'm just using a home computer, I don't think I have one.  Does Elevating to "RunAs" imply a user account that you can log-into? My feeling is that I would need to create an Admin account to do this so that I can get the credential as follows:

PS> Set-Alias -name su -value start-process -nnw -wait -Credential (Get-Credential -User Admin) powershell

PS> su

????

Update2:

Tried to get it working with .NET Api as follows.  It works to start subshell, but still not granting Admin Rights to sub-shell:

```
function su {
    $s = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{}
    $s.FileName        = "powershell"
    $s.Verb            = "runas"
    $s.UseShellExecute = $false

    $c = [System.Diagnostics.Process] @{}
    $c.StartInfo = $s
    $c.Start() | out-null
    $c.WaitForExit()
}

function isadmin {
    ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
}
```

Update3:

My conclusion is that for Diagnotics.Process, the "Verb" parameter requires that UseShellExecute = $true.  because Verb is an Action provided to the Windows Shell Launcher.  when UseShellExecute = $false, the Execuatable is directly called, bypassing the Windows Shell Launcher and its Verb Action.

Comment: The short answer, I believe, is "no." However there are console alternatives that provide multiple tabs that you could use, such as [console](https://github.com/cbucher/console).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think you'd be able to do this is write a C# program that loads two separate instances of the PS engine and have the second one execute under a different `System.Security.Principal` :(

Answer (score 0):

-RunAs is nothing to do with user accounts, it is simply for starting a session with elevated privilege. If your user account is permitted to do this, you may be prompted to approve this. If not, you will be asked for credentials. If you are just using the account you created when you installed the OS, you will have admin rights (think of all the times you install something and the User Access Control dialogue appears - this is requesting elevated permission).

Unfortunately you cannot get the 'su' behaviour you want in Windows by design. The way that parameter are sets are configured (so as not to allow you to escalate privilege inside a session) is an intentional security feature.